# What dimensions and metrics can replace GA 3 properties in GA 4 (GA - Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

There is an old version of Google Analytics that calculates the number of visits to a certain page.
**1**.`$result = $analytic->get($start_date, $end_date, "ga:pageviews", ["filters" => "ga:pagePath=~my url"] );`
The metric "ga:pageviews" and a filter along the path are used, as well as other code

**2.**.`$result = $analytic->get($start_date, $end_date, "ga:users", ["filters" => "ga:landingPagePath=~my url"] );`

Same design with different parameters.

It is necessary to transfer everything to Google Analytics version 4.

In the first case, instead of the "ga:pageviews" metric, I use totalUsers and a filter by pagePath. As I learned that "ga:pageviews" did not add version 4 and they advise using it. But the data in comparison is very small and I already doubt that I took the right parameters. Although I read somewhere that in version 4 it no longer reads bots.

In the second case, I used totalUsers and a filter by landingPage.

Also, the data will be more modest. Did I do it right, is there any page where a list of properties of version 3 is collected and how it can be replaced with properties of version 4.

The ones I used were taken from the [official website](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema?hl=en).

Client for working with API from [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data)

Please tell me what metrics and indicators should be used. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can not just port it like that.  The system is completely different.    There are no page views.    There are only events

Comment: There is a `views` metric that can be used in GA4 when looking at `page_location` type dimensions. There isn't the concept of `unique pageviews` but that could easily be swapped out with active users as that should only look at the total number of users who landed on a particular page.